# Access .class'es and .jar's from a .jsp

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I got Tomcat 7.0.62 and I just want to get a `.jsp` up and running with access to the database and possibly other .class'es in other files.  I made up a foo class and try to put declare `<% foo bar = new foo(); %>` in my `.jsp` but it does not recognize foo as a type.  I put foo.class in the WEB-INF/classes directory because that's where I read Tomcat looks.

Outside of Tomcat I am able to get the Java functionality I want as a stand-alone program.  It's when I try to put it into Tomcat with `.jsp` that Tomcat just refuses to see what I want.

I suspect the problem is with deployment.  Tomcat doesn't give the `.jsp` access to the *.class'es* or the `ojdbc6.jar` I want unless it's properly deployed as a webapp?  I'd rather not mess around with .war's.  How can I get it so that when I log onto **www.mydomain.com** it serves up my index.jsp with access to ojdbc6.jar and my foo.class?  Right now it serves up nothing because I undeployed the `/` app.  How can I redeploy `/` and give my `.jsp` the accesses I want?

Comment: Is your "foo" class in a `package`? Tomcat certainly does give `.jsp` files "access" to those classes.

Comment: No it's not using the package word anywhere in the source code for the class I want to use, so I just put it right in WEB-INF/classes directory.  Why is your word access in quotes?  What's that mean?

Comment: Put your Java class into a package, then use `import` within your JSP with the correct package and class name. Can you post the code to a sample JSP that does not work?

Comment: <% foo bar = new foo(6); %> <%= bar.get(); %>  where bar.get() should return the int 6, and jsp of course knows how to print an int.  I put public class foo { int i; public foo(int i) {this.i = i;} public int get() { return i; }} into foo.java, compiled into foo.class and put int WEB-INF/classes.  Perhaps you're right about putting in a package p before the class definition and then putting the accordingly resultant .class file into WEB-INF/classes/p.

Comment: My .jsp file was in the . directory and WEB-INF was a subdirectory of the . directory.

Comment: You really shouldn't start your way of programming these days anymore, there are quite a lot discussions out there about avoiding scriptlets: http://www.theserverside.com/feature/Top-5-reasons-that-JSP-scriptlets-suck

Answer (score 0):

JSP files (just like regular Java classes) can't reference classes that aren't specifically imported.

You'll need something like this at the top of your page:

```
<%@page import="foo" %>
<% foo bar = new foo(6); %>
<%= bar.get(); %>
```

You may find that the `import="foo"` does not work because, generally speaking, every class ought to be in a package. I seem to recall a requirement in the servlet (or JSP) spec that says all classes must be in a package, but I may just be inventing that since it's a good idea.